# Why is scp copying more bytes than it should

Tags: scp

I'm copying the Xcode.app from one computer to another using scp and it seems to have copied more than the file size and it's still copying. It 4.94GB (I didn't compress it), but nettop on the destination machine says 7430MB have been copied so far and it hasn't stopped yet. nettop on the source machine doesn't have any activity that corresponds to the copy.

The command I used

```
scp -rp paul@192.168.16.178:/Applications/Xcode.app /Applications/
```

nettop on the destination machine:

```
ssh.636                                                                                         7662 MiB          21 MiB   178 KiB  2029 KiB  1044 B
tcp4 192.168.16.108:50145<->192.168.16.178:22                    en1     Established        7662 MiB          21 MiB   178 KiB  2029 KiB  1044 B    13.53 ms   512 KiB   128 KiB        BE
```

Any ideas why it has copied over 7GB when the file is only 4.94GB?
Source and destination machines are iMac and Mac mini, **copying over a wifi local network.**

**Update**: Copy finished and when I check Xcode's size on the destination machine it's a whopping 10.07GB. I don't understand how Xcode should have doubled in size during the copy. My only theory is that .app directories are already compressed and that scp uncompresses them.

Cheers!

Comment: Perhaps there are symbolic links in the Xcode.app directory which get copied (but are not counted on the source machine)?

Comment: Maybe, running `du -L` to get file size with links followed results in `du: Too many symlinks at`.

Comment: That was spot on @mtak!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a page](https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works) describing how the SCP protocol works. The notable fact is that it can only transfer files and directories; there's no protocol support for symbolic links. In fact, SCP will treat each symbolic link as if it were an actual file or directory.

My copy of Xcode.app is 4,936,956,797 bytes according to the OS, and *find* tells me it has 7,499 symbolic links. We can trick *scp* into pretending to copy Xcode.app in order to see how much data it writes:

```
$ scp -rf Xcode.app < /dev/zero | wc -c
 8746268376
```

And we can do the same with *tar*:

```
$ tar cf - Xcode.app | wc -c
 5018552320
```

Tar can handle symbolic links, so it only writes a little more data than is actually in the directory structure. Scp can't handle symbolic links, and it's expanding each link into an actual file or directory.

Comment: +1. For a copy I suggest tar (and gzip if your connection is slow but your CPU is fast), then copy that, then untar on the receiving end. I believe rsync also can preserve symlinks. It's worth noting that @paulvs should really redo this with proper symlink copies - its more than just taking up too much space, those symlinks exist for a reason, so that multiple locations can refer to the same file and if that file changes or is updated, the updated version is also accessible through the symlinks. You could end up with a very unstable xcode some day if you don't.

Comment: Excellent answer @Kenster, using the scp command you posted I got the same size as what what arrived at the destination machine. Curiously the tar command gives an output 1.4GB larger than what Finder says the size is (they both should be ignoring symbolic links as I understand).

Comment: Tar has some overhead. There's an I think 512-byte header for each file, plus the file contents. Symbolic links have to be represented. I don't know how the finder counts symlinks when it's calculating the size of an app. Tar format is described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html) if you're interested.